# Is Sending a File Over a Network Faster Than Downloading?

Tags: c#, server, ftp, client

Alright, so I'm creating an application, and in it, the clients need to communicate with the server as soon as it launches. So I have two ideas for this. (A) I could have it so that the client sends a message to the server using TCP/IP to tell it what it needs, and the server sends that back over the connection, or the client just downloads a file from a web server.

Since both are transferring the same file over the network, both should be the same speed right? Well I don't know, that's why I'm asking. And I know that somebody will probably say "oh well try it yourself", and I'm sure I could if I got a runtime operation and used that with both, but I don't have my server set up yet, and I would change how it operates severely if I knew ahead of time.

So, is it faster to download from a web server, or contact a server and have it send the information over? And if there's any better idea as for getting info from the server, let me know!

Comment: HTTP will have a little more overhead but since it doesn't sound like you are trading stocks or running an online casino I doubt you would notice the difference.

Comment: It should be faster to send the information over a raw socket than a web server. Web server communications come with overhead, most of which you won't need. Will the difference be noticeable? Highly doubtful. I would favor the web server approach in most cases simply because it's a tested protocol with ready-made methods to handle the nitty gritty details. You're going to have to deal with message framing and such if you roll your own transmission code.

Comment: @itsme86 So, (not saying that this is exactly a setback, but just making sure that I understand downloading from a web server) I would then need a domain name and a server on which my file is for it to download, right? (aka if I didn't have a domain name and didn't want to use a free one subdomain, it would cost money)

Comment: @Jumanji You would need that *regardless* if you are downloading from an external machine and want to take advantage of DNS vs knowing the IP of the server. Assuming you don't have a static IP on the web somewhere... its a moot point really

Comment: You don't necessarily need a domain name, you can subdomain a site or CDN or storage service like Microsoft Azure, Amazon AWS, etc., if you don't care about the domain.

Comment: No.  If you connection is going over Wifi the download speed is faster than the upload speed.  So the answer depends on the medium being used for transmission.

Answer (score 2):

Your two operations are; from a network perspective, identical:

1. Client establishes TCP socket to server
2. Client sends request for file
3. Server responds with file

Using HTTP as the format of the request doesn't change the nature of the operation. You do have to deal with the overhead of going through the web server logic, but that is almost certainly negligible in comparison to the actual network operation.